# modify the jquery validation plugin to show messages in input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Pls does anyone know how I can get the error/sucess messages in the Remember the Milk example of the jquery validation plugin (http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/#) to show up in the input field.

My forms are inside very small boxes. I did some research and messed around with the script used on the site. I see where the message is being appended to the form label but I dont know the jquery method needed to get the error/success message to show up in the input field. Also Remember the Milk used table for their form, which I didnt do in mine. My forms are pretty much the same as the demo on the jquery validation page.

jquery validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#demo

Thanks.

Comment: Error messages inside input controls??

Comment: yep basically...Error/success messages..note that my success message is just a little tick that I want to show up on the right corner of the field...just like https://www.inkling.com/ ...if u try to sign up you can see what I'm saying

Comment: Just in case of email.. if i am entering a long email address, a red border is there, but it didn't show the validation message?

Comment: oh I see...when you click on the dropdown then click on signup towards the bottom of the box...then you will get a popup...type in a random number in the email field and you will see what I have in mind...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do like place a div or span besides that input element. Initially the div will be hide and according to the validation you can show or hide the div will show the error message.

I am just trying one sample..

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
<div id="errorDiv" style="display:none">Error Message</div>
<div id="okDiv" style="dispaly:none">Ok</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
               email:{
                  required: function (element) {
                      if($(element).text()=="")
                      {
                          $('#errorDiv').show();
                          $('#okDiv').hide();
                      }
                      else
                      { 
                          $('#errorDiv').hide();
                          $('#okDiv').show();
                      } 
                  }
           }
  });
});
```

Just try like this

Comment: ok I will give this a try. Is there a simpler and generalized way to do this cos I have a lot of form fields to validate. It would be tedious to add error IDs to each field...thanks

Comment: @justcode : Dnt know.. may be there.. You need to customize the default error label accordingly... But in the link provided above i think they are doing something i have done above..